# How to handle Multiple views using ajax and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am developing a quiz ui where multiple views will be shown to the user viz,
1. Instructions
2. Question #1 and on clicking next Question #2 and soon
3. User can at any time end the test,
and so on.

I have developed this using all the views on client side and transferring only data from server side using ASP.NET .

But rendering of these views on the client side is not looking good on IE, FIREFOX.
Now I am thinking of sending this UI alongwith data from server side.

Before doing this I thought of asking to you guys.
Help plz !

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: its ajax based multiple views, data for all the views coming from the server. now considering of sending UI for the views alongwith data from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way of bringing the UI to your quiz page using Ajax could be using jQuery Ajax features http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

More specifically you want to use the load method, where you will pass the url of the view that contains the UI, and then inject that HTML into a specific element in the quiz page DOM